# Como monitorar o Progresso de uma query de INSERT VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, vb.net

Estou armazenando arquivos em um banco de dados *SQL server* usando um campo varbinary(max). Gostaria de saber se é possivel detectar o progresso do upload do arquivo (que no caso seria um *INSERT* na tabela) usando o VB.NET.

Caso não seja possível obter o progresso, uma estimativa já ajudaria.

Comment: Como é feito o insert? Você transforma o arquivo num array de `byte`?

Comment: Sim, transformo em um array de byte. Normalmente o insert leva cerca de 4 a 8 segundos pra terminar pois são aquivos pequenos. Queria monitorar o progresso se possivel

Comment: Jovem, cê tem como postar o código do insert?

Comment: @LINQ acho que não vai postar não. O ideal é fechar por falta de clareza já que é muito antiga para migrar.